# Django JSON Builder like Rails JBuilder or RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, django-views, rabl

Anybody knows if there is any package related to templating json like Rails JBuilder or RABL gems ?

I have this code and want to separate out json rendering code and business logic code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # Business logic
    # hidden ----------

    # rendering logic
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    another = {'something': 'hello'}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data':data,'another':another}), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tastypie!](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie)

Tastypie is a webservice API framework for Django. It provides a convenient, yet powerful and highly customizable, abstraction for creating REST-style interfaces.

[django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit that makes it easy to build Web APIs.

Comment: I'm a newbie and trying to code in a good way. Could you please provid e me an example of simple workflow how you separate your json rendering code from business logic code ?

Comment: django-tastypie is model api. You can stick with this and follow this example http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: thanks got the workflow, really appreciate your help :)